# I get an Access blocked Authorization Error when I try to access my application via authetication

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, backend, passport.js

I am adding Google OAuth to my web app project. However, whenever I enter the url containing the callback, I get an error "Missing required parameter: scope Learn more about this error

If you are a developer of Library Managment Platform, see "error details"

Error 400: invalid_request

Below is my code;

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: process.env.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: 'https://library-management-api-n823.onrender.com/auth/google/callback',
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const user = {
        id: profile.id,
        displayName: profile.displayName,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
      };
      return done(null, user);
    }
  )
);
```

```
// Google OAuth routes
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

app.get(
  '/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  (req, res) => {
    // Save the session and redirect
    req.login(req.user, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving session:', err);
      }
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  }
);
```

I have the secret keys in the .env file. I have cross-checked to make sure that they are the same in the google console. This code however redirects me to the error page. I have installed all relevant dependencies, including passport and passport-google-oauth20.